# Access global variable from other document

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm starting with OOP in PHP and I have an issue with global variables.

Example of my current structure:

`test.php` REQUIRES `globals.php` and also INCLUDES `classes.php`.

---

`globals.php` has this code:

```
global $something;
$something = "my text";
```

---

and `classes.php` looks like this:

```
global $something;

class myClass {
    public $abc = "123";
    public $something;

    public function doSomething() {   
        echo $this->abc."<br>";
        echo $this->something;
    }
}

$class = new myClass();
$class_Function = $class->doSomething();

print_r($class_Function);
```

---

At the end, `test.php` only shows "123".

I tried using "include()" instead of "require" for `globals.php` but didn't work. Neither did including `globals.php` in `classes.php`.

Comment: `$this->something != $something`

Comment: @u-mulder Why not?

Comment: Because `$this->something` is a property of a class, and `$something` is jsut a variable.

Comment: But `$this->something` isn't accessing to the class variable?

Comment: If you are learning OOP, then totally forget global variables and ask the correct way to do what you actually want to do.

Comment: `$this->something` is accessing a property of a class. Class __knows nothing__ about any outer variables

Comment: So how can I access to that variable?

Comment: Lot's of ways depending on how you want to build the app, but simply you can use constants: `define("something", "my text");` then use `echo something;`, but better to probably use another class with class constants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->something` was never initialized. The global `$something` is totally outside of scope and is not related to the class attribute `$this->something`. If you need to access a global inside a function or method you need to declare it as global:

```
public function doSomething() {   
        global $something;
        echo $this->abc."<br>";
        echo $something;
    }
```

However you need to stop using globals because is not a good solution. If you need do define some constant values that are global to your system it's prefered to use define()

```
define("SOMETHING","My text")
```

And then you can access it in any part of your code:

```
echo SOMETHING;
```

Also see: [PHP global variable scope inside a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488407/php-global-variable-scope-inside-a-class)
and [Use external variable inside PHP class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094467/use-external-variable-inside-php-class/17094513#17094513)

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I access to `SOMETHING` in the class? `public SOMETHING;` throws this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SOMETHING' (T_STRING), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)`

Comment: For defines, you don't need to declare inside the function. Only use `echo SOMETHING;`  (it Doesn't need `$`)

Comment: I get an approach using `public $something = SOMETHING;`

Comment: Yes, you can initialize an attribute using the define.